# Adding prototype to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, object

I have a list like:

ATOM      1  N   LYS A   1      37.995  20.521   9.231  1.00 31.96
ATOM      2  CA  LYS A   1      38.067  19.342  10.141  1.00 30.87
ATOM      3  C   LYS A   1      36.817  18.477  10.027  1.00 28.29
      ...
ATOM     10  N   GLU A   2      36.835  17.337  10.707  1.00 24.26
ATOM     11  CA  GLU A   2      35.709  16.412  10.692  1.00 19.83
ATOM     12  C   GLU A   2      35.496  15.870  12.098  1.00 18.02
...
I read this list line by line and than parse it. After parse i expect the result like this:

```
[ { resName: 'LYS',
    resSeqNum: 1,
    atoms: { atomName: ' N  ', x: 37.995, y: 20.521, z: 9.231 }, { atomName: ' CA ', x: 38.067, y: 19.342, z: 10.141 }, { atomName: ' C  ', x: 36.817, y: 18.477, z: 10.027 }, ... },  
[ { resName: 'GLU',
        resSeqNum: 2,
        atoms: { atomName: ' N  ', x: 36.835, y: 17.337, z: 10.707 }, { atomName: ' CA ', x: 35.709, y: 16.412, z: 10.692 }, { atomName: ' C  ', x: 35.496, y: 15.870, z: 12.098 } } ] ]
```

I try it several ways but results don't like i want. Here is my code:

```
var someData = ["ATOM      1  N   LYS A   1      37.995  20.521   9.231  1.00 31.96           N",
                "ATOM      2  CA  LYS A   1      38.067  19.342  10.141  1.00 30.87           C",
                "ATOM      3  C   LYS A   1      36.817  18.477  10.027  1.00 28.29           C" ] ;    
var protein = [];               
var parse;

function parser(line){
    parse = {
        resName: line.substring(17, 20),
        resSeqNum: parseInt(line.substring(22, 26)),
        atoms: {
            atomName: line.substring(12, 16),
            x: parseFloat(line.substring(30, 38)),
            y: parseFloat(line.substring(38, 46)),
            z: parseFloat(line.substring(46, 54))
        }
    }
    return parse;
}
for(var i=0; i<someData.length; i++){
    protein.push(parser(someData[i]));  
}
console.log(protein);
```

I give a some data for test my code. This code's results like that:

```
[ { resName: 'LYS',
    resSeqNum: 1,
    atoms: { atomName: ' N  ', x: 37.995, y: 20.521, z: 9.231 } },
  { resName: 'LYS',
    resSeqNum: 1,
    atoms: { atomName: ' CA ', x: 38.067, y: 19.342, z: 10.141 } },
  { resName: 'LYS',
    resSeqNum: 1,
    atoms: { atomName: ' C  ', x: 36.817, y: 18.477, z: 10.027 } } ]
```

Can you give me any advice for that?

Comment: What results do you expect?

Comment: If you're bothered by the whitespace in output strings, `.trim()` them.

Comment: I edit it now. Result should be like first code block

Comment: Actually i don't have a problem for parse line. I have a problem for create dynamic object

Comment: From your expected result I understand the question as: make **1** object per `resName`, add `atoms` to it grouped by this property. I think the choice of words is a bit unfortunate since a `prototype` in javascript is something different... Also, there are some misplaced brackets in your expected output: from the comma's in `atoms` I expect this should be an array, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an `array` for your atoms. Right now, every line gets its own object. There's no grouping by "res name". Here's how you can do it in two steps:

- For each atom,
- Check the res name,
- If it's one we haven't seen, create a new object with an atom array
- If we've already seen it, use the previously created object
- push the new atom to the array

```js
var someData = ["ATOM      1  N   LYS A   1      37.995  20.521   9.231  1.00 31.96           N",
                "ATOM      2  CA  LYS A   1      38.067  19.342  10.141  1.00 30.87           C",
                "ATOM      3  C   LYS A   1      36.817  18.477  10.027  1.00 28.29           C",
                "ATOM     10  N   GLU A   2      36.835  17.337  10.707  1.00 24.26",
                "ATOM     11  CA  GLU A   2      35.709  16.412  10.692  1.00 19.83",
                "ATOM     12  C   GLU A   2      35.496  15.870  12.098  1.00 18.02"] ;    

// Parsing logic
var getRes = line => line.substring(17, 20);
var getResSeqNum = line => parseInt(line.substring(22, 26));
var getAtomName = line => line.substring(12, 16);
var getX = line =>  parseFloat(line.substring(30, 38));
var getY = line => parseFloat(line.substring(38, 46));
var getZ = line => parseFloat(line.substring(46, 54));


var parsedBySeq = someData.reduce(function(result, line) {
    var resKey = getRes(line);
    var resSeq = getResSeqNum(line);
    var newAtom = {
        atomName: getAtomName(line),
        x: getX(line),
        y: getY(line),
        z: getZ(line),
    };
    
    if (!result[resKey]) { // First time we've seen a res with name 'resKey'
        result[resKey] = { 
          resName: resKey, 
          resSeqNum: resSeq, 
          atoms: [newAtom] 
        };
    } else { // Previously encountered atoms had the same name, add this one to it
        result[resKey].atoms.push(newAtom);
    }

    return result;
}, {});


var parsedArr = Object.keys(parsedBySeq).map(k => parsedBySeq[k]);

console.log(parsedArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

**Edit:** As requested, in an "old school" for loop:

```js
var someData = ["ATOM      1  N   LYS A   1      37.995  20.521   9.231  1.00 31.96           N",
                "ATOM      2  CA  LYS A   1      38.067  19.342  10.141  1.00 30.87           C",
                "ATOM      3  C   LYS A   1      36.817  18.477  10.027  1.00 28.29           C",
                "ATOM     10  N   GLU A   2      36.835  17.337  10.707  1.00 24.26",
                "ATOM     11  CA  GLU A   2      35.709  16.412  10.692  1.00 19.83",
                "ATOM     12  C   GLU A   2      35.496  15.870  12.098  1.00 18.02"] ;    

// Parsing logic
var getRes = line => line.substring(17, 20);
var getResSeqNum = line => parseInt(line.substring(22, 26));
var getAtomName = line => line.substring(12, 16);
var getX = line =>  parseFloat(line.substring(30, 38));
var getY = line => parseFloat(line.substring(38, 46));
var getZ = line => parseFloat(line.substring(46, 54));


var parsedBySeq = {}, // This map is used to store unique keys
    i, line, l, resKey, resSeq, newAtom;

for (i = 0, l = someData.length; i < l; i+= 1) {
  line = someData[i];
  resKey = getRes(line);
  resSeq = getResSeqNum(line);
  newAtom = {
    atomName: getAtomName(line),
    x: getX(line),
    y: getY(line),
    z: getZ(line),
  };
    
  if (!parsedBySeq[resKey]) { // First time we've seen a res with name 'resKey'
        parsedBySeq[resKey] = { 
          resName: resKey, 
          resSeqNum: resSeq, 
          atoms: [newAtom] 
        };
    } else { // Previously encountered atoms had the same name, add this one to it
        parsedBySeq[resKey].atoms.push(newAtom);
    }

}

var parsedArr = Object.keys(parsedBySeq).map(k => parsedBySeq[k]);

console.log(parsedArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Can we use for loop instead of reduce?

Comment: Sure! Reduce might be a bit harder to read when you're moving stuff around. Define `var parsedBySeq = {}` before your loop and change `result` to `parsedBySeq`.

Comment: If it is possible can you write this with for loop?

Comment: I included a rewrite to a for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate for that.